# Using capturing groups in GWT regexp

Tags: java, regex, gwt

I have some code using Oracle regex that I want to port to GWT.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String expression = "(abc)|(def)";
    String source = "abcdef";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

    while (matcher.find())
    {
        if (matcher.start(1) != -1)
        {
            // it's an "abc" match
        }
        else if (matcher.start(2) != -1)
        {
            // it's a "def" match
        }
        else
        {
            // error
            continue;
        }

        int start = matcher.start();
        int end = matcher.end();

        String substring = source.substring(start, end);
        System.out.println(substring);
    }
}
```

I’ve tried porting it to the GWT regexp library, but it uses capturing groups through the start(int) method, which doesn’t seem to be supported in GWT regexp.

Is there a way to simulate this behaviour?

APIs references:

[Oracle regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

[GWT regexp](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/package-summary.html)

Comment: Take a look at: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html What are you missing from this?

Answer (score 7):

From [GWT - 2.1 RegEx class to parse freetext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323024/gwt-2-1-regex-class-to-parse-freetext) :

Here's how you can iterate through them in GWT:

```
RegExp pattern = RegExp.compile(expression, "g");
for (MatchResult result = pattern.exec(source); result != null; result = pattern.exec(source)) 
{
    if (result.getGroup(1) != null && result.getGroup(1).length() > 0)
    {
        // it's an "abc" match
    }
    else if (result.getGroup(2) != null && result.getGroup(2).length() > 0)
    {
        // it's a "def" match
    }
    else
    {
        // should not happen
    }

    String substring = result.getGroup(0);
    System.out.println(substring);
}
```

*(edit: added "g" in Regexp.compile)*

Comment: Nice, I started to try to write this myself, but got bogged down in the differentce, rather than just continuing on.

Comment: The example here will result in infinite loop. Finding the first and the same occurrence in every iteration. You need to pass "global flag" to the compile method.

RegExp pattern = RegExp.compile(expression, "g");